# Looking for a one word to explain 'overspent and overearned'

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

I am trying to put words as column labels for financial table. One column will track all 'amount that has been spent extra' and one column for tracking all 'amount that has been earned extra'.

I came up with words like 'amount overspent' and 'amount overearned'. But I'm not sure if these are grammatically correct or not.

Are these two correct already, or any suggestions for similar words? It would be nice if you could suggest just two words, just to keep in concise.

Answer (score 2):

A column label is not a sentence, and does not need to be strictly grammatical.

It does matter, however, who the intended audience is. If it is for yourself alone, then it can be as informal as you like, provided it is clear to you. If it is for a client or a boss, it need ti seem professional.

The labels  "*amount overspent*" and "*amount overearned*" seem quite acceptable to me. Another option would be "*Excess spending*" and "*Excess earnings*" There are many other ways in which these concept could be expressed.

It might be a good idea to include a note defining the meaning of entries in each of these columns in more detail that a heading can do.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I decided to go with overworked/underworked - they sound more fitting. But I really appreciate your explanation.